# Input file does not run function if empty

Tags: javascript, function, file, input, is-empty

If I insert png it works, if I insert jpg it works, but if I leave the file empty it doesn't work, why? The file should be png or empty.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var fileTypecheck = document.getElementById("file").files[0].type.replace(/(.*)\//g, '');
  
  if(fileTypecheck == "png" || fileTypecheck.length == 0){
  
      alert("File is png or 0");
  }else{
      alert("File is NOT png or 0");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"  onchange="loadFile(event)" accept="image/png">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Hint: `files[0]`

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error message? If so, what is the error message? At a guess, the problem is that you are trying to access a property on `files[0]` without first checking that `files` has a length. If no files are selected, then `files` will be an empty array, so `files[0]` will be undefined, which means adding `.type` will throw an error. Consider using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an `<input type="file"/>` has no files selected its `HTMLInputElement.files` property is empty, so `files[0]` is `undefined`.

BTW, you **should not** rely on the browser to always accurately tell you of a file's type: browsers typically populate the `File.type` property from their host OS's file-extension-to-MIME-type registry which is not reliable and often outdated.

That said, change your code to this: note that I've added *defensive programming* steps to actually verify things instead of making assumptions:

```
function myFunction() {

    const inp = document.getElementById("file");
    if( !inp || inp.type !== 'file' ) throw new Error( "'file' input element not found." );
    
    if( inp.files.length !== 1 ) {
        alert( "Please select a single file first." );
        return;
    }

    const file = inp.files[0];
    if( file.type === 'image/png' ) {
        // OK
    
    }
    else {
        alert( "Please select a PNG file." );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When there is no file the index of `files[0]` does not excist. You can add a question mark ([Optional_chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)) to `files[0]` so it does not break down when there are no files.
Then you can change `fileTypecheck.length== 0` to `!fileTypecheck` since it will be undefined when there is no file.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var fileTypecheck = document.getElementById("file").files[0]?.type.replace(/(.*)\//g, '');
  
  if(fileTypecheck == "png" || !fileTypecheck){
  
      alert("File is png or 0");
  }else{
      alert("File is NOT png or 0");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/png">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```